# How do i hide progress bars when training an ANN from keras?

Tags: python, keras

I am using python 3.5.4 (Anaconda distribution) and keras (Tensorflow back-end) to train an ANN for classification. I usually run my code from the Ipython console, but i get the same errors if i just call the script from the normal terminal on my Ubuntu machine.

I have a problem where if i re-run my code without restarting the terminal it will freeze and do nothing - CPU also shows that it is not used (0-1% usage on them).
So i read somewhere that i should disable the progress messages because that could be the reason it blocks.

So i tried to use **verbose=0** in GridSearchCV, but it didn't work - the messages keep showing.

I also tried using it in model.fit(), but then i get a message that **"fit() got an unexpected keyword argument 'verbose'"**

```
search = GridSearchCV(estimator=model1, param_grid=params, scoring='accuracy', cv=10, n_jobs=-1, verbose=0)

grid_search=search.fit(X_train, y_train, verbose=0)
```

Any idea how i can fix this?

Comment: Try to add `'verbose`: [0]` to your `params`.